# How to join a two kafka streams in flink (1 being running and 2nd being static with only few records like a master table)

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I want to enrich my 1st stream with the help of the 2nd stream like the flowing records keep joining with the 2nd stream like a lookup which I want to keep in memory forever like a table.
Any code example or any flink API I could use which would fit in this use-case.

Answer (score 0):

You can find an example of a connected stream with a shared state in the Ververica training page: https://training.ververica.com (Stateful Stream Processing, Slide 13)

```
public static class ControlFunction extends KeyedCoProcessFunction<String, String, String, String> {
  private ValueState<Boolean> blocked;
    
  @Override
  public void open(Configuration config) {
    blocked = getRuntimeContext().getState(new ValueStateDescriptor<>("blocked", Boolean.class));
  }
​
  @Override
  public void processElement1(String controlValue, Context context, Collector<String> out) throws Exception {
    blocked.update(Boolean.TRUE);
  }
    
  @Override
  public void processElement2(String dataValue, Context context, Collector<String> out) throws Exception {
    if (blocked.value() == null) {
      out.collect(dataValue);
    }
  }
}


public class StreamingJob {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
        
    DataStream<String> control = env.fromElements("DROP", "IGNORE").keyBy(x -> x);
    DataStream<String> data = env
      .fromElements("Flink", "DROP", "Forward", "IGNORE")
      .keyBy(x -> x);
    
    control
      .connect(data)
      .process(new ControlFunction())
      .print();
    
    env.execute();
  }
}
```

In your case, you would need to keep the contents of the 2nd stream in the `KeyedCoProcessFunction` state and have the 1st stream read from the state to join it with its elements. You'll need to think how to key your streams and what kind of state to use, but that would be the main idea.